# Java Wrapper equality test

Tags: java, wrapper

```
  public class WrapperTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer i = 100;
        Integer j = 100;

        if(i == j)
            System.out.println("same");
        else
            System.out.println("not same");
    }

   }
```

The above code gives the output of `same` when run, however if we change the value of `i` and `j` to 1000 the output changes to `not same`. As I'm preparing for SCJP, need to get the concept behind this clear. Can someone explain this behavior.Thanks.

Comment: Very interesting question, and I did not know Java behaved this way. I tend to use equals() whenever I can, so I have been lucky enough to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Java, Integers between -128 and 127 (inclusive) are generally represented by the same Integer object instance. This is handled by the use of a inner class called IntegerCache (contained inside the Integer class, and used e.g. when Integer.valueOf() is called, or during autoboxing):

```
private static class IntegerCache {
    private IntegerCache(){}

    static final Integer cache[] = new Integer[-(-128) + 127 + 1];

    static {
        for(int i = 0; i < cache.length; i++)
            cache[i] = new Integer(i - 128);
    }
}
```

See also: [http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas#Immutable_Objects_.2F_Wrapper_Class_Caching)

Answer (score 7):

Basically Integers between -127 and 127 are 'cached' in such a way that when you use those numbers you always refer to the same number in memory, which is why your `==` works.

Any Integer outside of that range are not cached, thus the references are not the same.

Answer (score 5):

@tunaranch is correct.  It is also the same issue as in this [Python question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers).  The gist is that Java keeps an object around for the integers from -128 to 127 (Python does -5 to 256) and returns the same object every time you ask for one.  If you ask for an Integer outside of this fixed range, it'll give you a new object every time.

(Recall that `==` returns whether two objects are *actually* the same, while `equals` compares their contents.)

*Edit*: Here's the relevant paragraph from [Section 5.1.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7) of the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/):

> If the value *p* being boxed is `true`,
>   `false`, a `byte`, a `char` in the range
>   `\u0000` to `\u007f`, or an int or short
>   number between -128 and 127, then let
>   *r1* and *r2* be the results of any two
>   boxing conversions of p. It is always
>   the case that *r1* == *r2*.

Note that this also describes what happens with other types.

Answer (score 4):

It's to do with equality and autoboxing: http://web.archive.org/web/20090220142800/http://davidflanagan.com/2004/02/equality-and-autoboxing.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile. This is what I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Integer
>       Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Integer

```
at WrapperTest.main(WrapperTest.java:5)
```

Variables i and j are instances of Integer object. Don't compare instances of object using "==" operator, use "equals" method instead.

Greetings

Comment: I guess you are using java 1.4..try it with Java 1.5