# Java String object creation

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of the expression “new String(…)” in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390703/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-expression-new-string-in-java)

Hi,

1) What is difference in thers two statements:

```
String s1 = "abc";
```

and

```
String s1 = new String("abc")
```

2) as i am not using new in first statement, how string object will be created

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390703/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-expression-new-string-in-java

Comment: Here's another good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009228/strings-are-objects-in-java-so-why-dont-we-use-new-to-create-them/2009272#2009272

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, the compiler knows the value of the String s1. Thus, all strings with the same value will use the same memory locations:

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "abc";
```

Although there are two String references (s1 and s2), there is only one "abc" sequence in memory. The `new` operator is not needed because the compiler does the job.

In the second case, the compiler doesn't perform the evaluation of the String value. Thus, the sentence will generate a new instance of String, at runtime:

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = new String("abc");
```

The constant "abc" in line 1 references the same memory as the constant "abc" in line 2. But the net effect of line 2 is the creation of a new String instance.

Comment: So String s1 = "abc"; is creating any object/instance or just allocating memory

Comment: Since String objects are immutable, there is no difference between both things. Indeed: you can invoke the String methods in a string constant:

int stringLength = "hello".length();

Answer (score 3):

The first will use a fixed String that will be compiled in the code. The second variant uses the fixed String and creates a new String by copying the characters. This actually creates a new separate object in memory and is not necessary, because Strings are immutable. For more information, you can read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable).

The main advantage of having internalized strings is that the performance is better (e.g. through caching etc.).

As a programmer there is no real upside to creating a new String, unless you come by the following example:

```
String sentence = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
String word = sentence.substring(5);
```

Now the word has a reference to the sentence (substring does not copy the characters). This is efficient while the sentence is also used, but when this one is thrown away you use a lot more memory than needed. In that case a new String can be created:

```
word = new String(word);
```

Comment: ... upvoted to early - I doubt, that the example is correct, because the `String(String s)` constructor doesn't create a new char array but keeps the reference, too. Exactly like `substring(int a, int b)`, which internally calls `new String(int start, int length, char[] chars)`

Comment: It checks for exactly that case and creates a new, resized array.

Comment: The `String(String s)` constructor does make a copy when the original value is much longer that the view.

From the javadoc:

`Initializes a newly created {@code String} object so that it represents the same sequence of characters as the argument; in other words, the newly created string is a copy of the argument string`