# Reference id of two String in constant pool

Tags: java

Visit [String Constant Pool Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150628/string-constant-pool-java) !

```
public class StringLiterals {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1="This is ";
        s1=s1+"my book";
        String s2="This is my book";
        System.out.println(s1==s2);

    }
}
```

O/P:False

Expecting O/P:True

Comment: `"This is" + "my book"` is first of all `"This ismy book"` which lacks a space and therefore no matter how you compare it not equal.

Comment: "This is " + "my book" is also giving false.

Comment: After providing the link, you really should write an actual question to clear up all this confusion that has been caused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code compiles into

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #16                 // String This is 
       2: astore_1      
       3: new           #18                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       6: dup           
       7: aload_1       
       8: invokestatic  #20                 // Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
      11: invokespecial #26                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      14: ldc           #29                 // String my book
      16: invokevirtual #31                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      19: invokevirtual #35                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      22: astore_1      
      23: ldc           #39                 // String This is my book
      25: astore_2      
      26: getstatic     #41                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      29: aload_1       
      30: aload_2       
      31: if_acmpne     38
      34: iconst_1      
      35: goto          39
      38: iconst_0      
      39: invokevirtual #47                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
      42: return
```

which is equivalent to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("This is ");
    sb.append("my book");
    String s1 = sb.toString();
    String s2 = "This is my book";
    System.out.println(s1 == s2);
}
```

because

```
s1=s1+"my book";
```

is not a constant expression - you are reading the value of a variable and the compiler will assume that you could have changed it in the meantime. If you want that

> Strings computed by constant expressions (§15.28) are computed at compile time and then treated as if they were literals. [JLS (§3.10.5)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)

applies you would have to change your code to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "This is " + "my book";
    String s2 = "This is my book";
    System.out.println(s1 == s2);
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String s1a = "This is ";
    final String s1b = "my book";
    String s1 = s1a + s1b;

    String s2 = "This is my book";
    System.out.println(s1 == s2);
}
```

and now you are guaranteed that it works. Second example compiles to

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #16                 // String This is 
       2: astore_1      
       3: ldc           #18                 // String my book
       5: astore_2      
       6: ldc           #20                 // String This is my book
       8: astore_3      
       9: ldc           #20                 // String This is my book
      11: astore        4
      13: getstatic     #22                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      16: aload_3       
      17: aload         4
      19: if_acmpne     26
      22: iconst_1      
      23: goto          27
      26: iconst_0      
      27: invokevirtual #28                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
      30: return
```

and as you can see loads 2 times String `#20`

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this will help clear things up.

```
    String s1 = "This is";
    s1 = s1 + " my book"; // Note the space
    String s2 = "This is my book";
    String s3 = "This is my book";
    System.out.println(s1==s2); // False
    System.out.println(s2==s3); // True
```

"Strings are only put in the pool when they are interned explicitly or by the class's use of a literal." Hence, you cannot concatenate strings with the + operator and expect it to be put into the string constant pool.

Comment: There we go! Someone who visited the link!

Comment: Not strictly true. Concatenating two constants will give a constant.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Could you explain it better?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you are missing a space. I assume that's just a mistake.

You have probably seen something like this:

```
"This is"+" my book" == "This is my book"
```

Why does that work? Because it's all *compile-time constants* [JLS 7 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). In particular "literals of type String" and "The additive operators + and -".

There's also "Simple names [...] that refer to constant variables". But this doesn't apply as your variable is not `final`.

But it's not something you should particularly need to know about. Just use `equals` for `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use == to compare two Strings, as the == operator is asserting that s1 and s2 point to the same *memory location*, and not that the contents are equal.  To compare the contents of two Strings to see if they contain the same content, use String's `.equals()` method. Plus you needed an extra space on the `s1=s1+` line.

Code:

```
{
public class StringLiterals {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1="This is";
    s1=s1+" my book";
    String s2="This is my book";
    System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));

    }
}
```

If you want to use ==, you will then have to use this:

```
public class StringLiterals
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String s1 = "This is my book";
    String s2 = s1;
    System.out.println(s1 == s2);
  }
}
```

Because *Strings* are objects, their == act differently than ints, chars, and other primitives.

Comment: He was expecting them to be at the same memory location

Comment: The compiler will concatenate string literals and intern then and it works then. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5

Comment: I have modified my answer to show a way to use both .equals() and ==, in which both return true.

Comment: I think this is not related with the *implicit* OP' question.

Comment: You modified answer, while being correct, does not address OP's concerns.

Answer (score -1):

The presence of + operator results in new String. Here `s1 = s1 + " my book"`, s1+ " my book " implicitly creates new String and store its reference to s1. So it is different from s2