# what happens with new String("") in String Constant pool

Tags: java, string

if i create a string object as

```
String s=new String("Stackoverflow");
```

will String object created only in heap, or it also makes a copy in String constant pool.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `String x = "Stackoverflow"` will be placed in constant pool, `String x = new String("Stackoverflow")` will be placed on the `heap` as well as `String s = new String("")`.

Comment: You should find a detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150628/string-constant-pool-java

Comment: @GuyBouallet note that that answer seems to be contradicting answers given here, as it says it is put to both constant pool and the heap

Comment: @eis Yes.  After the line of code that OP has quoted, the value `"Stackoverflow"` WILL be in the constant pool; and the object referred to by `s` WILL be on the heap.

Comment: Agree with @DavidWallace. In my answer I've given another example with different construct approach, which will not cause a copy in constant pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My answer is YES!**

Check the following code first:

```
String s0 = "Stackoverflow";
String s1 = new String("Stackoverflow");
String s2 = s1.intern();

System.out.println(s0 == s1);
System.out.println(s1 == s2 );
System.out.println(s0 == s2);

//OUTPUT:
false
false
true
```

`s0` hold a reference in the string pool, while `new String(String original)` will always construct a new instance. `intern()` method of `String`  will return a reference in the string pool with the same value.

Now go back to your question:

**Will String object created only in heap, or it also makes a copy in String constant pool?**

Since you already wrote a string constant `"Stackoverflow"` and pass it to your `String` constructor, so in my opinion, it has the same semantic as:

```
String s0 = "Stackoverflow";
String s1 = new String(s0);
```

which means there will be a copy in String constant pool when the code is evaluated.

But, if you construct the `String` object with following code:

```
String s = new String("StackoverflowSOMETHINGELSE".toCharArray(),0,13);
```

there won't be a copy of `"Stackoverflow"` in constant pool.

Answer (score 10):

You only get a string into the constant pool if you call `intern` or use a string literal, as far as I'm aware.

Any time you call `new String(...)` you just get a regular new `String` object, regardless of which constructor overload you call.

In your case you're also ensuring that there *is* a string with contents `"Stackoverflow"` in the constant pool, by the fact that you're using the string literal at all - but that won't add another one if it's already there. So to split it up:

```
String x = "Stackoverflow"; // May or may not introduce a new string to the pool
String y = new String(x);   // Just creates a regular object
```

Additionally, the result of a call to `new String(...)` will always be a different reference to all previous references - unlike the use of a string literal. For example:

```
String a = "Stackoverflow";
String b = "Stackoverflow";

String x = new String(a);
String y = new String(a);

System.out.println(a == b); // true due to constant pooling
System.out.println(x == y); // false; different objects
```

Finally, the exact timing of when a string is added to the constant pool has never been clear to me, nor has it mattered to me. I would guess it *might* be on class load (all the string constants used by that class, loaded immediately) but it could potentially be on a per-method basis. It's possible to find out for one particular implementation using `intern()`, but it's never been terribly important to me :)

Comment: Yes, but he DID use a String literal.  The literal goes in the constant pool, and the new object goes on the heap.

Comment: @DavidWallace: But the use of the literal doesn't in itself add to the constant pool - it ensures that the value is *in* the constant pool, but it may already be there. I've clarified this in an edit.

Comment: I think the wording of the question implies that the literal wasn't in the constant pool to start with.

Comment: @DavidWallace - 1) I don't read it that way, and 2) the String object corresponding to a String literal is *always* in the string pool.

Answer (score 5):

In this case you are constructing an entirely new String object and that object won't be shared in the constant pool. Note though that in order to construct your `new String()` object you actually passed into it a `String` constant. That `String` constant *is* in the constants pool, however the string you created through `new` does not point to the same one, even though they have the same value.

If you did `String s = "Stackoverflow"` then s would contain a reference to the instance in the pool, also there are methods to let you add `String`s to the pool after they have been created.

Comment: `"stackoverflow"` will be in the pool, `s` won't.

Comment: Yes, so we end up with two copies of `"stackoverflow"` - the literal one in the constant pool, plus `s` on the heap.

Comment: Omoro is correct. In this case the `new String` is being created from a String constant though. So the constant is added to the string pool, from that constant a new String object is created in the heap.

Comment: @TimB, Your (perfectly correct) comment seems to contradict your answer.

Comment: @Omoro the literal `"stack overflow"` is first created and goes to the pool then a new String is creating using the copy constructor which will not be in the pool.

Comment: Also, opposing pool with heap is misleading: the string pool may well be on the heap too (it is in java 8 for example)...

Comment: @DavidWallace how does it contradict the answer? He's constructing an entirely new String object so that object won't be shared...the fact that another one is also created that will be shared doesn't invalidate that point.

Comment: Well, your answer seems to say that the value doesn't end up in the constant pool; and clearly it does.  I believe you understand correctly what happens, but the first sentence of your answer is really quite unclear.  I'm wondering if there's a way that you could clarify that you meant that the object referred to by `s` is not in the constant pool, even though the value `"Stackoverflow"` is in the constant pool.  That would certainly earn you my upvote.

Comment: @DavidWallace It says that the string instance `s` points to does not go in the pool. There is a different `String` with the same value in the pool but I don't comment on that either way. I've edited the answer to hopefully remove the ambiguity though.

Answer (score 2):

The new String is created in the heap, and NOT in the string pool.

If you want a newly create String to be in the string pool you need to `intern()` it; i.e.

```
String s = new String("Stackoverflow").intern();
```

... except of course that will return the string literal object that you started with!!

```
String s1 = "Stackoverflow";
String s2 = new String(s1);
String s3 = s2.intern();

System.out.println("s1 == s2 is " + (s1 == s2));
System.out.println("s2 == s3 is " + (s2 == s3));
System.out.println("s1 == s3 is " + (s1 == s3));
```

should print

```
s1 == s2 is false
s2 == s3 is false
s1 == s3 is true
```

And to be pedantic, the `String` in `s` is not the `String` that was created by the `new String("StackOverflow")` expression.  What `intern()` does is to lookup the its target object in the string pool.  If there is already a String in the pool that is `equal(Object)` to the object being looked up, *that* is what is returned as the result.  In this case, we can guarantee that there will already be an object in the string pool; i.e. the String object that represents the value of the literal.

Answer (score 1):

A regular java object will be created in the heap, and will have a reference `s` type of `String`. And, there will be String literal in String Constant Pool. Both are two different things.