# How does String invoke constructors?

Tags: java

The first code is shown below:

```
String s = "hello";
```

The second code is shown below:

```
String s = new String("hello");
```

Question: Are the two codes invoking the same constructor of `String(char[])`?

`String` has a `private final field char value[]`. Why is it set to a `final` field? Such we will create a new `String` every time we invoke change the value of string. What is the purpose to set the field `char value[]` to `final`?

Comment: `What is the purpose to set the field char value[] to final?` -- it makes the string immutable.

Comment: [String Constant Pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505952/java-strings-immutability/23505989#23505989) comes into picture in first case.

Comment: Not at all. Visual makes more sense to remember things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question: Are the two codes invoking the same constructor of String(char[])?

No, absolutely not.

The first form bakes the the string content directly into the bytecode, then uses the `ldc` (load constant) instruction to load it from the string pool.

Importantly, *every* occurrence of the string constant "hello" will refer to the same object.

Compare that with your second form, which will create a new string every time you execute the statement.

As to the details of the field being final: it's a private field anyway, so you shouldn't care. But it's final because Java strings are immutable - there's no reason why you'd *want* to change the value of it. (In itself that isn't enough to enforce immutability; anyone with access to that `char[]` can modify the contents of the array.)

Comment: Are you saying that `"a" == "a"` but, `new String("a") != new String("a")` ?

Comment: Why set String to be immutable? I know there is a class called StringBuilder in JAVA is mutable. Why not combine these two classes into one?

Comment: @Ryan Check any of the dozens of existing versions of that question on the site.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this is answered elsewhere, but I'm too lazy to look it up --

When you declare a "string literal" in Java, that literal gets allocated as a Java String object during class loading of the containing class.  (And, incidentally, the String is "interned".)

So when you say `String s = "Hello";`, you're merely assigning a reference to the pre-existing String object to the variable `s`, and no matter how often in the program you do that assignment, you do not create any more instances of the String.

`new String`, on the other hand, *always* creates a new String object.

The `char[]` array in the String object is where the actual value of the String is stored.

(Note that a String is immutable -- you cannot change it once created.  When you assign a new value to as existing `String` reference, you are assigning a *new* object, not updating the existing `String` object.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Question: Are the two codes invoking the same constructor of String(char[])?
```

You are assuming that "hello" is a char[], but it is not, it is a String. You can invoke String methods to it, like `"hello".charAt(0)`

So in:

```
String s = "hello";
```

no constructor is invoked. "hello" is already a String and is assigned to the variable `s`.

And in

```
String s = new String("hello");
```

the constructor `String(String)` is invoked.

For your second question: `value` is final because in Java, Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "hello";
```

s is a reference to a [String Litteral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526493/how-does-string-invoke-constructors)

To quote the referenced JLS section about String litterals:

*(..)a string literal always refers to the same instance of class String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.(..)*

```
String s = new String("hello");
```

Now this s is a reference to a String object you are creating by calling [String constructor with a single String argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28java.lang.String%29).

```
Are the two codes invoking the same constructor of String(char[])?
```

No, [there isn't a call within this constructor to the overloaded constructor you are referring to](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String has a private final field char value[]. Why is it set to a final field?
```

So that it cannot be changed once set by the constructor. This is one the Steps needed for String to serve as [immutable object](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29).