# Is a instance val more costly then companion object val?

Tags: kotlin

Is there a good reason (performance-wise) to replace a:

`val SOME_CONST = "value"`

with

```
companion object {
    val SOME_CONST = "value"
}
```

Does adding a `@JvmStatic` annotation changes the outcome?

Comment: You can use a stand alone object for constants, not necessarily a companion ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, a `val` stored in `companion object` is more efficient. You can use [Kotlin bytecode viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538049/kotlin-bytecode) to find out what these options are compiled to.

Here are the things I noticed that might affect performance:

- Companion object `val` is stored only once, unlike instance `val`, which is actually stored in each instance thus increasing the instances memory footprint (`String` literal [is stored in constant pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150628/string-constant-pool-java), but an instance will have a reference to it) and instance creation time (during the construction, a field must be filled in).
- Accessing companion object `val` several times in a row works better with CPU cache than using `val` in different instances: it has better [locality of reference](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Locality_of_reference). Dereferencing different instances to access the `val` in them will likely lead to CPU cache misses, which is not good for performance.

  However, if the `val` is only used inside instance methods of the same class, the described effect will scarcely affect performance because the methods will likely dereference `this` anyway, and this may even work better, not causing probable cache miss while accessing the companion object.
- Adding [`@JvmStatic`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-static/) makes the access a bit faster. Without it, accessing the value requires getting static `Companion` reference and calling `getSOME_CONST()` on it. With `@JvmStatic`, there will be static method `getSOME_CONST()` (skipping `Companion`). There's also [`@JvmField`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/) that makes a public field that can be accessed directly without even calling getter.

  But JIT compiler will likely optimize the getter access of the first two cases, so that the effect of the annotations will be barely noticeable.

Also, apart from performance, instance `val` has semantics of a value that might be different for each instance, so `companion object` seems to fit the case of global constant value better.