# how many objects are created for String str=new String("test")

Tags: java

I have gone through this [String Constant Pool Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150628/string-constant-pool-java) but dint get any clarity I want to know how many objects are created i.e memory space allocated when

```
String s=new String("stackoverflow");
```

1. Are 2 object created if stackoverflow is not available in string constant pool i.e one in string constant pool and the other in heap memory and s will be pointing to the one in heap memory..?
   or
2. Only one object is created in heap memory...?

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what cases would this knowledge be useful? The only one I can think of is if you're writing a java compiler.

Comment: please answer in 1 or 2 I have gone through the other question but dint get any clarity