# Concatenation of two string in String constant pool in java

Tags: java

Since concatenation of two strings will make new string object in string constant pool so why following code evaluates to No.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abcd";
        String s1 = "ab";
        String s2 = "cd";
        s1 = s1+s2;
        if(s1==s)
            System.out.println("YES");
        else
            System.out.println("No");
            }
}
```

Comment: You can get some additional information there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150628/string-constant-pool

Comment: And be clear about the difference between equals and ==

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`s1+s2` is not a compile-time constant expression because `s1` and `s2` aren't final (despite them being assigned compile-time constant values).

As such, the value is computed at runtime: the result is not the same instance as the one in the constant pool, despite the value being the same.

Comment: ... as `new String() != ""`

Answer (score 1):

Here `s` has complied time assign value and `s1` is in runtime both are not same instance String pool. Use equals method to check equals in string for this case ex: `s1.equals(s)`.

If both values computed in runtime this will work.

```
String s1 = "ab";
String s2 = "cd";
String s3;
s1 = s1+s2;
s3 = s1;
if(s1==s3)
    System.out.println("YES");
else
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

It gives you output YES.

And if both values assigned in compile time then it will work.

```
String s = "abcd";
String s1 = "abcd";
if(s1==s)
    System.out.println("YES");
else
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

This code also gives you output YES

Comment: My question is why s1 and s doesnot refer to same string in string constant pool

Comment: if s ="abcd" and s1 = "abcd" then both reference will be same