# when does java create a new object for string

Tags: java

When we do

```
  String a=new String("mac");
String b=new String("mac");

if(b == a)
{
    System.out.println("condition 1 is true");
}
if(b.equals(a))
{
    System.out.println("condition 2 is true");
}
```

condition 1 fails and condition 2 is true since b and a are two different objects

But when we do

```
String a="mac";
String b="mac";

    if(b == a)
    {
        System.out.println("condition 1 is true");
    }
    if(b.equals(a))
    {
        System.out.println("condition 2 is true");
    }
```

Both the conditions are true. Why didn't java create a new object for second case. If java creates a new object only when we use `new()` then if we give different values to both the strings then what happens internally in java?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009228/strings-are-objects-in-java-so-why-dont-we-use-new-to-create-them and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java

Comment: How many duplicates ... let me count them ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare like below, Java create String literals in the String constant pool, and both references `a` and `b` will refer that String object `"mac"` in the pool

```
String a="mac";
String b="mac";
```

So, both `==` and `.equals()` returning true.

But, when you create String object by using `new` operator, String objects are created in the heap like other regular objects in java.

So `==` operator will return false, since both references referring two different object in the heap.

Comment: yes this is concept of pool and heap

Comment: also, see String#intern() http://java-performance.info/string-intern-in-java-6-7-8/