# What is the difference between "ABC" and new String("ABC")?

Tags: java, string, difference

What is difference between `String str = "ABC"` and `String str = new String("ABC")`?

Comment: `String str = "abc"; is a String literal,where as String str = new String("abc") is a String Object.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## String

In Java `String` is a [special object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009228/strings-are-objects-in-java-so-why-dont-we-use-new-to-create-them) and allows you to create a new `String` without *necessarily* doing `new String("ABC")`. However `String s = "ABC"` and `String s = new String("ABC")` is not the same operation.

From the javadoc for [`new String(String original)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(java.lang.String)):

> Initializes a newly created String object so that it represents the
>   same sequence of characters as the argument; [...]
>
> Unless an explicit copy of original is needed, use of this constructor
>   is unnecessary since Strings are immutable.

In other words doing `String s = new String("ABC")` creates a new instance of `String`, while `String s = "ABC"` reuse, if available, an instance of the [String Constant Pool](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/19/the-string-constant-pool/).

## String Constant Pool

The String Constant Pool is where the collection of references to `String` objects are placed.

`String s = "prasad"` creates a new reference only if there isn't another one available. You can easily see that by using the [`==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) operator.

```
String s = "prasad";
String s2 = "prasad";

System.out.println(s == s2); // true
```

[image]

<sub>*Image taken from [thejavageek.com](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/19/the-string-constant-pool/).*</sub>

---

`new String("prasad")` always create a new reference, in other words `s` and `s2` from the example below will have the same value but won't be the same object.

```
String s = "prasad";
String s2 = new String("prasad");

System.out.println(s == s2); // false
```

[image]

<sub>*Image taken from [thejavageek.com](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/19/the-string-constant-pool/).*</sub>