# what is the difference between the 2 cases; in java strings?

Tags: java, string

why do these statements give different answers?

```
String s1="hello world";
String s2="hello world";
 System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));//true
    System.out.println(s1 == s2);//true
```

2nd case;

```
String s1=new String("hello world");
String s2=new String("hello world");
 System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));//true
    System.out.println(s1 == s2);//false
```

Comment: Search a little bit in internet, then ask here if there was not found.

Comment: Read the accepted answer to this Question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009228/strings-are-objects-in-java-so-why-dont-we-use-new-to-create-them

Answer (score 1):

`s1.equals(s2)` compares the content of the two strings whereas `s1 == s2` compares the objects' references.

Since both s1 and s2 are two different instances of the String class, their references are not equal. The `==` operator behaves this way for all Objects.

Answer (score 0):

`==` just compares two references - i.e. it tests whether the two operands refer to the same object. `s1` and `s2` are two different objects so that's why the comparison is `false`.