# Is it possible to instantiate objects without constructor in Java

Tags: java, oop, object, instance, literals

When learning about String literals vs String objects, I came across the fact that there are 2 possible ways to instantiate a variable of type String

```
//Using literals
String s1 = "text";

//Using constructor
String s2 = new String("text");
```

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow create an class and instead of instantiating it with a constructor, one could instantiate it using a literal

This is what I mean

```
class Value {
    int value;
    //Some methods
}

Value val = 10; //Program automatically sets val.value = 10
```

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: No.............

Comment: Java doesn't give you a way to do this. But even where you use literals for objects, constructors and other factory methods end up being invoked under the hood anyway.

Comment: "there are 2 possible ways" there are others too.

Comment: Mechanism like this exists in C++, but not in Java.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009228/strings-are-objects-in-java-so-why-dont-we-use-new-to-create-them

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible. The closest thing that Java has to this is [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), where you can write something like:

```
Integer val = 10;
```

and the compiler automatically turns that assignment into one involving the primitives cache (there is a fixed set of primitive values that are guaranteed cached: boolean true/false, byte and char values 0-127, and int values -128 to 127, [As per the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7). Although a JVM may, and almost always does, have a more extensive primitives cache than that).

Comment: Nit: that assignment *won't* create a new instance. Owing to caching.

Comment: @AndyTurner That's why I said "convert" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No. Although you can write `String s1 = "text";`, the java compiler automatically creates an object. This may be the reason to misguide you. But it happens inside.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the scenarios its not possible. Creating a `String` like you have and assigning a `int` value both are using constructors even we can't see it directly.

How ever there are rare scenarios like this. Please read [this](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue175.html). Will be good to add to your knowledge :)