# Instance methods in String Class in java

Tags: java

How String instance methods such as isEmpty and toUpperCase being called without creation of String Object.

```
"myString".toUpperCase();
```

since toUpperCase is not static method, how its being called without creation of new String()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strings are objects in Java, so why don't we use 'new' to create them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009228/strings-are-objects-in-java-so-why-dont-we-use-new-to-create-them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string literal like `"myString"` *does* create a `String` object¹, even if you don't explicitly see a `new String()` call in the code. Consider `String s = "myString";` which couldn't work otherwise! So you can call any method on it as usual.

---

¹ Or reuses an existing one, see [string pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357021/reputable-people-keep-answering-duplicates-whats-the-solution

Comment: @Ayush I believe this is a different question than [the one marked as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009228/strings-are-objects-in-java-so-why-dont-we-use-new-to-create-them), although they are strongly related: "why do I seem to get a String object even though I didn't write new" shows that the asker did _not_ know that a literal creates a String, whereas "why do we not use new to create String objects" shows that the asker _did_ know that fact.

Comment: @Ayush That said, I may have been guilty of answering duplicates and will be more careful about it in the future, thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: That's alright, although regardless of the OP knowing it or not, they would have, after reading the dup. It's marked as a dup now anyway so it's all good.