# different output for same code in Java

Tags: java, wrapper

I am new to java. I know somewhat about the wrapper classes and primitive datatypes, but what I have come across is surprising. On changing the values of the variables i and j from 1000 to 100, the output changes from false to true. I need to know the mechanism behind this.

```
class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer i=1000,j=1000;
        if(i==j)
            System.out.println("true");
        else
            System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```

the above code gives me "false" while..

```
class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer i=100,j=100;
        if(i==j)
            System.out.println("true");
        else
            System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```

the above code give me "true"

Comment: This or a similar question come up every day. Is this some texbook example? I've never had this problem in real programming live.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Wrapper equality test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456575/java-wrapper-equality-test)

Comment: @OrhanC1 take a look add you edit of the question, looks like you added surplus }

Comment: @bummi Ahh! You're right. Sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Caching in Wrapper Classes

Integer has *internal cache* for values ranging from -128 to 127.

So for numbers within this range, the same instance of `Integer` is returned.  `==` compares by instance, and so the same instance is used for `100`.

Source JDK 1.6:

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    final int offset = 128;
    if (i >= -128 && i <= 127) { // must cache 
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + offset];
    }
        return new Integer(i);
    }
```

[Caching in wrapper classes Java](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/03/06/object-initialization-best-practices-internal-caching-in-wrapper-classes/)

### Purpose of Caching

The purpose is mainly to *save memory*, which also leads to faster code due to better cache efficiency.

### Use `.equals` when comparing value, not identity

If you are comparing two `Integer`s, you should use `i.equals(j)` just like you would do to correctly compare the value of `String`s. Also keep in mind that any operation which will unbox an `Integer` places an implicit call to  `Integer.intValue()`, so remember to make these calls carefully, knowing when your `Integer` might be null.

Comment: No problem, great answer, just thought I'd make that clear in case it wasn't obvious.

Comment: I'd like to know  who has choose this range of value (-128 to  127) and why ? 

Why not a higher range ?

Answer (score 1):

To compare the contents of objects (instead of their identity) use `equals` instead of `==`. This will give consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper class `Integer` has internal cache for -127 to 127. So when you assign same values which are within this range same instance will be returned. For 1000 two different 'new'ed instances are returned giving false on == comparision.

If you use `int` instead of `Integer`, results will not be surprising. For consistent result with your approach, use `equals()` method instead of `==`.